# Problem with Cloud Function deployment to schedule daily Cloud SQL export to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I made a Cloud Function to export Cloud SQL database to Cloud Storage using this article: 
https://medium.com/@kennethteh90/how-to-schedule-daily-cloud-sql-export-to-google-cloud-storage-4c1bd360af06

This is my function:

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const {auth} = require("google-auth-library");
var sqladmin = google.sqladmin("v1beta4");

exports.exportDatabase = (_req, res) => {
  async function doBackup() {
    const authRes = await auth.getApplicationDefault();
    let authClient = authRes.credential;
    var request = {
      project: "project ID",
      instance: "instance ID",
      resource: {
        // Contains details about the export operation.
        exportContext: {
          kind: "sql#exportContext",
          fileType: "SQL", // CSV
          uri: `gs://bucketName/folderName/backup-${Date.now()}.gz`,
          databases: ["database"]
        }
      },
      // Auth client
      auth: authClient
    };

    // Kick off export with requested arguments.
    sqladmin.instances.export(request, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
      res.status(200).send("Command completed", err, result); 
    });
  }
  doBackup();
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "export-database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "google-auth-library": "3.1.2"
  }
}
```

As Runtime I use Node.js 8. 
Function to execute: **doBackup()**

Error I receive during:

**Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named doBackup()**

Could anybody help me with this error ? I don't understand why I receive this and can't go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named doBackup()**

Your Cloud Function to execute name, according to the error message is `doBackup` but the function that you are calling in `index.js` is `exportDatabase`. Please make sure that these names are the same, for example change `exportDatabase` to `doBackup` or change function to execute to  `exportDatabase`

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your advice halped. And I think the problem was with that I put " () " after name of function to execute. Any way, thanks !